# Add sequentially-named variables in a resulting field without using 200 var lines? [PDF Form]

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, pdf, sum

I'm trying to sum variables with sequential names in a field (`sum`) for a PDF Form, but the code is not working.
New to all things programming, I've read a bit on arrays but only found cases where all the variables are thoroughly declared (written) before the problem. My case is exactly to find a working code that "arrays" sequentially-named variables inside a sum operation.
My variables are named `textbox1`, `textbox2`, ..., `textbox200` (all of which being varied integer numbers), so I'd very much like to find a way to avoid having to write down 200 `var [i]=this.getField("textbox[i]");`
and tidy up 200 var lines...
I've tried this:

```
var x=this.getField ("sum")
x.value = 0;
for(var i = 0; len = 201; i < len; i++) {
x.value += (var [i]=this.getField("textbox[i][1]"));
}
```

Probably got some logic/language principle all wrong, could someone give me directions please? EDIT: also, considering pdf form js seems to need a `.value` after any variable, that is probably another missing aspect in the code, but I'm not sure where it would be placed. tried altering to `(var [i].value=this.getField("textbox[i][1]"))`, still the sum field shows nothing.

Thanks.

PS. I realize PDF forms can perform sum operations quite easily by selecting the fields to be added, but considering I need it to have more flexibility than only adding the fields (and not willing to click 200 checkboxes out of 500+), I need to use the javascript console for the calculation(I think).

EDIT2: Tried this too, adding the .value where it seemed to make sense.

```
var x=0;
for(var i=1; i<=200; i++) {
var y=this.getField("textbox"+i)
x.value = x.value + y.value
} 
event.value = x.value
```

Still no response from the sum field box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code in EDIT2, the problem is with the "x". You define it as a number, and a number does not have a value property.

Therefore, this should work:

```
var x = 0 ;
for (var i = 1 ; i <= 200 ; i++) {
x += this.getField("textbox"+i).value*1 ;
}
event.value = x ;
```

We multiply the field value with 1, in order to force it to a number, something which is necessary to deal with empty fields (an empty field has the value of the empty string, which means that the numbers are not added but concatenated).